# How to find the value of $\vec{v}$ in the equation $\vec{v} - a[\vec{v}{\times}\hat{y}] = b\vec{E}$

Tags: vectors

How to solve the equation and directly determine the value of $\vec{v}$ in the equation?
$$\vec{v} - a[\vec{v}{\times}\hat{y}] = b\vec{E}$$
where,
$\vec{v}$ and $\vec{E}$ are in the $\hat{x}$ direction, and $a$ and $b$ are scalars.

edit: edited the vector

Comment: Context- Ran into this problem when trying to simplify and obtain equation no. 4 in the following research paper

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231974732_Laser_second_harmonic_generation_in_a_rippled_density_plasma_in_the_presence_of_azimuthal_magnetic_field

Comment: What is $\vec{E}^2$? You can't square a vector. Also, how we can we answer your question if you’re “not fully sure” even about the information you’re providing us?

Comment: vector = scalar isn't a valid equation. Please [edit] the post and fix it. Also, note you mention $\hat{x}$ but the equation has $\hat{y}$. This post _needs attention_.

Comment: What is the operation $[ \text{(vector)}]$ supposed to do?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Maybe we can substitute $\vec{E}^2=\vec{F}$ for some $\vec{F}$. Since the LHS is a vector, the RHS has to be one too.

Comment: If $\vec v$ is in the $\hat x$ direction, $\vec v\times \hat y$ is in the $\hat z$ direction. Then the left hand side is **not** in the $\hat x$ direction, while the right hand side it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert $\vec{c} = \vec{a}\times \vec{b}$ into a matrix-vector product with the following trick (it is called the cross product operator matrix).

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  \vec{c} & = [\vec{a}\times] \vec{b} \\
  [\vec{a}\times] & = \pmatrix{0 & -a_z & a_y\\ a_z & 0 & -a_x \\ -a_y & a_x & 0}
\end{aligned} $$

So the LHS of the equation above is

$$ \vec{v} -a (\vec{v} \times \hat{y}) = \vec{v} + a ( \hat{y} \times \vec{v} ) = \left( \mathbf{1}+ a [ \hat{y}\times] \right) \vec{v} $$

<sub>where $\mathbf{1}$ is 3×3 the identity matrix, and $[\hat{y}\times]$ the 3×3 cross product operator.</sub>

This makes an equation like $\vec{v} -a (\vec{v} \times \hat{y}) = b \vec{E}$ solvable

$$ \boxed{ \vec{v} = \left( \mathbf{1} + a [ \hat{y}\times] \right)^{-1} b \vec{E} }$$

Comment: Why would you use $1$ for the identity matrix and not $I$? That’s really misleading

Comment: Because this way $1$ is the identity operator under multiplication for both scalars and matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $\vec v$ is in the $x$-direction, $\pmatrix{v_x\\0\\0}\times\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\v_x}=\vec c$. To find $\vec v$, solve for the components algebraically and separately. In this case, that’s just $v_x$; if $\vec v$ is in the $x$-direction, then $v_y=v_z=0$.

$$\begin{align}
v_x-ac_x &= bE_x \\
v_x &= bE_x +ac_x \\
&= bE_x +0 \\
\end{align}$$